# "Post Your Answer" should be disabled for those users who have already posted an answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In my opinion, **"Post Your Answer"** section should be disabled for those users who has already posted an answer on the question.

**Reason:** I have found that many users posted multiple answers on the same question. And if they don't have the reputation to post a comment then they use the answers to post comments.

**Pros:**

- This will reduce multiple answer spam.
- It will reduce low quality post, as if users can't post multiple answers they will modify their own answer, and this will improve their post.

But I want to other users' opinions too; is this good idea or not? If a user posts multiple answers on the same question then what action should be taken?

Comment: I don't really see what problem this solves. If a user posts multiple answers that aren't answers (e.g. are comments, or "edits" to previous answers), they will get downvoted, flagged and deleted. If a user posts multiple answers that *are* answers, then... good!

Answer (score 11):

The main reason this wouldn't work is because problems can be solved in different ways, hence you can add multiple answers.

So if a user wants to post 2 separate answers, to solve a problem using different methods, having them as individual posts allows separation of voting, which would help future visitors distinguish the different solutions.

The general consensus maybe that one solution is better than another, so it will get more votes over time.

If the answers were merged together, which can be done, then it's harder to separate the good from the not so good part of the answer. People might comment and say they like the first part of the answer and the second part isn't so good, but this information would be buried in comments and more difficult to decipher for future users.

With regards to users posting comments as answers or abusing this, there are flags available for that.

Comment: User can post the one or more solution on the same answer. Is not?

Comment: @CodeLღver they could but, as this answers points out, **that's not desirable**. If there are two different approaches, two answers from one user is perfectly acceptable - you *are* warned when trying to create the second that you should consider editing the first, though.

Comment: they can, but if the solutions are substantially different, they _may_ be better as separate answers so they can be voted on / or accepted in isolation. If both answers are together in one post, then the accepting user isn't likely to implement both of the solutions, they will choose the best or preffered part.