# Fragment Identifiers on Headings within Answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, permalink

Today I posted an answer featuring two different methods of achieving what the user was asking for depending on certain external content. After posting my answer I did some digging and found that the more appropriate solution was the second part of my answer.

The second part of my answer flowed on from the first, which meant that moving the more important second section above the first would have required a lot of text alteration. To avoid doing this, I edited my answer to include an *"upon further analysis, it looks like the second part of my answer is more appropriate for what you're trying to do"*.

As my answer was moderately long, I then thought it'd be nice to link the user past the first part's text and examples directly to the second part of my answer, but to my disappointment found that there is no way of doing this as the headings are standalone elements with no identifiers or related `a` elements.

I'm sure there are also a lot of cases whereby only certain parts of an answer are applicable to a users' needs. Would it be possible to add fragment identifiers to headings to allow for navigation like this?

For example, here is a heading:

> ## Hello, world!

The markup for this is a pretty basic:

```html
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
```

Not much we can do with this. However with the simple addition of an `id` attribute or an `a` element with a `name` attribute...

```html
<h1 id="123456789-hello-world">Hello, world!</h1>
```

```html
<h1>
  <a name="123456789-hello-world"></a>
  Hello, world!
</h1>
```

...we can link directly to that heading by appending `#123456789-hello-world` to the end of the page's URL. *123456789 here being the ID of the answer, as currently used when linking directly to answers; this can be kept here to avoid collisions with other answers.*

With this in place, instead of linking to an answer and telling the user to find a specific section (*"check out [this answer's](http://example.com/Example-Answer) Foo section"*), we could link directly to that part for them (*"check out this answer's [Foo section](http://example.com/Example-Answer#Foo)*).

---

As this has already attracted a downvote, I figured I'd give an example use case. Here is a lengthy multi-part answer I posted a few weeks back: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29558231/1317805. The first part deals with static text and the second part deals with images; the entire answer is 2,648px tall.  If someone asked me for help with this issue but only needed help with images, I'd currently link them directly to that answer and tell them to scroll down to the *Handling custom marker images* section. However in an ideal world it'd be nice to be able to link directly to that heading, as the first part would be irrelevant.

Comment: Linking directly to an answer already uses a hash to jump down the page to the answer. You can't have two bookmark hashes in a URL.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen good point, but you wouldn't need to jump to the answer at all as you'd be jumping directly to the content. `#123456789` would become `#hello-world`. Regardless I've updated the question to include this: instead of `#hello-world` I've put `#123456789-hello-world`.

Comment: How about simply posting 2 separate answers if you are suggesting more than one solution to a problem? Then each can be linked to and voted on independently and you don't have to worry about bookmarking sections. I posted [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290582/57475) recently about multiple answers from a single user.

Comment: This is strange, they should allow anchors within posts, I also have a very long answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34215918/1886357) that I want to make a table of contents for. It isn't separate answers, but one multipart answer that ended up being a very complicated topic that required multiple sections. This limitation seems strange, no good reasons given to not allow it!

Comment: I asked this question again, hopefully a little more clear, and with replies to the attempted answer. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312498/add-a-link-within-a-question-or-answer

Answer (score -12):

I don't see this happening for several reasons.

1. We already use bookmark hashes in the URLs to jump to a specific answer. You cannot have more than one bookmark hash in a URL.
2. It opens up a possibility for abuse since anyone could try to put the same `id` or `name` in their answer.

---

If you really feel a part of your answer is more important than another, it makes more sense for you to reorganize your answer to put the most helpful information at the top.

Additionally, [you may post more than one answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) to a question. This would give you your desired behavior and you could easily link between the two answers.

Comment: Regarding point 1, did you neglect to read [my response](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290870/fragment-identifiers-on-headings-within-answers/290874#comment179596_290870) to your comment?

Comment: IF an answer is already logically ordered, it wouldn't make sense to reorganize it, and having more than one answer would be a mistake. Point 1 could be worked with, no? Also, I am unclear what 2 means or why it is a problem if someone puts the same name in their answer. How would that help them or constitute abuse?

Comment: Concern 1 seems trivial: we just have a hashmark to a point inside a answer instead of the whole answer. It's not like you have to hash a hash: nobody is asking for that.

Comment: Answering question twice is inappropriate, as 1) you don't control the order, so if the order is important among sections then vote mechanics would break it, and 2) different answers are not meant to be syntactic sugar, like paragraph breaks, but full answers that get an up or downvote all together.

Comment: Answering the same question more than once is appropriate if your answers are separate and distinct ways to answer the question.

You do not have control over the ordering, but you have control to link to the #hash of your answer in other answers, allowing you to jump back and forth between your answers.

Allowing `name` or `id` to create additional hash points in answers open up to abuse because other users can utilize the same `name` or `id` in their answer. Whatever answer that utilizes a duplicate `name` or `id` that is higher on the page would get the jump.

Comment: _..abuse because other users can utilize the same name or id in their answer_ That should be really easy to catch on the server, if the powers that be were interested in the feature at all..