# Feature request: Add a link within a question or answer

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

I wrote a [very long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34215918/1886357) to a question. This answer is divided into multiple sections. I would like to be able to link to individual sections rather than send people to the post to fish around for a particular section. In html, [this is done by adding anchors to the page](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html). This is not presently allowed at SO, and I would request that it be introduced as a feature: namely, that we can use anchors to create links to particular sections (lines) of questions and answers on Stack Overflow.

**Relevant questions**

Note this has come up twice before:

- [Fragment Identifiers on Headings within Answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290870/fragment-identifiers-on-headings-within-answers)
- [Is it possible to add html anchor in a StackOverflow answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303420/is-it-possible-to-add-html-anchor-in-a-stackoverflow-answer)

Neither has an accepted answer. The previous iterations of the question had idiosyncratic features that got people sidetracked. E.g., one answer suggested to just *reorder the content*, putting the most important stuff first, as if that would solve the problem. For a long, *logically ordered*, answer, this suggestion would not work.

Another person suggested to break up an answer into multiple answers, each of which already has its own link on SO. There are all sorts of problems with this. Different answers are meant to be different answers, not serve as paragraph breaks: especially if the order of the parts is important, breaking things up into different answers would not make sense as we have no control over their order. That is controlled by votes.

One answer said that only only one bookmark hash is allowed per url, and insinuated that this is a fatal problem with the suggestion. This seems something that would be trivial to overcome: just allow different names for different anchors within a question or answer. What is so fatal about that?

In general, it seems strange that SO posts seem to not have a natural way to link to particular places in questions and answers. It's like taking one of the cool features of the internet, and killing it. Why? This seems a natural and useful feature for longer questions and answers.

Note we explicitly discussed whether to ask this question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312285/better-to-reduplicate-or-to-edit-a-poorly-worded-question-with-no-good-answers). A [second post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312172/offer-a-bounty-and-add-details-to-a-question) says that in such a case it is best to simply ask a new question when the original doesn't have a satisfactory answer.

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a blog post.

Comment: @Braiam yes I discussed that in detail in my post, explaining why I am reasking, and linked to an explicit discussion of that: the two times it has been asked the answers are not accepted or very good (for reasons I outlined explicitly already in my post).

Comment: Incidentally, I was trying to make this a feature request, not a question...I will edit to make it more clear. I probably did it wrong as it is my first time making a feature request, but please dont' remove that tag it was my main goal. I know the answer to my question, I want to get a vote on the feature request.

Comment: @neuronet You posted a question asking if its possible.  That's not a feature request.  If you want to post a feature request you need to *actually request a feature*, at least at a minimum.

Comment: @Servy I was explicit about this, so not sure what you are saying. From my post: "This is not presently allowed at SO, and I would request that it be introduced as a feature: namely, that we can use anchors to create links to particular sections (lines) of questions and answers on Stack Overflow."

Comment: @neuronet No, you asked if it was possible, got an answer, and *then* edited that line into the question, to completely change what you're asking.

Comment: @Servy I edited to clarify my original intent. I originally had the feature request tag that you removed, so maybe you could have asked for clarification instead of editing: I edited it to make it more clear, as it was already pretty clear from the first two posts it wasn't possible.

Comment: @neuronet And yet you asked if it was possible anyway, you didn't request that it be added.  I have no idea why you asked if it was possible if you already knew that it wasn't, but you choose to do so anyway.  I removed the tag because you posted a question asking if it was possible; you didn't request a feature, so the feature request tag makes no sense.

Comment: @Servy I clarified the Q b/c I realized it was not clear when you removed the tag, that there was ambiguity. My intent was always to request this feature, hence the feature request tag I put in originally, that you removed! Then today you are asking about the original question, as if I didn't already clarify it. Not sure why, there was no attempt at trickery here, I truly just want this feature. Maybe b/c you feel you answered the question and then I changed it? I changed it because I realized you misunderstood my intent, when you edited my Q to fit your answer! lol This is very funny.

Comment: Why has this discussion been abandoned? Is there a technical limitation that prevent this from being implemented? I mean, that would be great to have a more flexible way of sharing answers. It may be nice to be able to point a detail inside an answer (a line of code, a code block, a section, etc.).

Comment: @cglacet  as time goes on, and the number of multipart answers increases, it is clear this would be a good feature. Lots of benefits very little downside. Pedantry notwithstanding.

Answer (score -5):

Clearly the question is just too broad, if it necessitates an answer that's that long.  SO answers shouldn't be this long in the first place.

But to answer your question, you cannot create anchors within a post.

Comment: The question is not broad, it is simple and specific, but for Python users giving an answer turns out to be a lot to it because it is about how the binding works under the hood.

Comment: @neuronet Either the information is important to answering the question, and thus the question is way too broad, or the vast majority of that answer is entirely off topic, and should be removed.  Either way, something is very wrong when there's an answer that's that long.

Comment: I would suggest it is impossible (and superficial) to say the answer or question is bad just by virtue of the length of the answer. There are lots of questions, and answers, that it would be useful to have links within. E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/1022743/1886357, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362687/the-net-2-0-sdk-programs-what-does-each-tool-do/2176970#2176970.

Comment: @neuronet Both of those questions are *completely* off topic for the site, and have no business being on SO at all.  Given that the *definition* of the Too Broad close reason is that the question cannot be answered within an appropriate length, I *can* say that if there is an answer that's that long then either the question is too broad, or the answer has lots of superfluous information.  SO answers really aren't supposed to be that long.

Comment: perhaps bad examples, but at any rate it seems the post under question is not like that. It is a specific question about Qt for Python, and a detailed answer. Maybe for some it is overkill (hence, the tl;dr), but for the original questionier (i.e., me) it was exactly what I was after. There can be, and are, longer answers (and questions) at SO (or meta-SO). I appreciate longer answers that take the time to explain things, rather than code snippets and cryptic explanations. This is a stylistic preference, not something objective that you can use to say X is bad because of length.

Comment: @neuronet The fact that you wanted to ask a question that is too broad, and post an answer that's not of an appropriate scope for an SO answer, in no way changes the fact that the question is too broad, or that the answer isn't of an appropriate scope for an SO answer.  if you want to just post blog posts/articles, that's fine, SO just isn't the place to do it.

Comment: @neuronet `[...] to say X is bad because of length.` It's not necessarily bad, it just doesn't belong on SO.  SO isn't a site for posting long form articles about entire subjects.  It's a place for specific, narrowly scoped questions.  There are other places where the content you want to post is appropriate, and you can feel free to post such content there.

Comment: that is not a broad question: it is a focused question about the default delegate used by Qt views.. So the problem isn't the question, though it could be the answer. Do you have a link to where SO explicitly prohibits, discourages longer answers? Is there something wrong with an answer being relatively comprehensive? Someone else could answer it and make a nice pithy answer, and it will get voted up if people prefer that. At least is my understanding, though maybe I missed the memo, but this seems like stylistic attack not substantive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98184/discussion-between-neuronet-and-servy).

Comment: @neuronet Feel free to look through the help center yourself if you want to see some of the guidelines on scope.  You're supposed to have already read it (you're not allowed to ask a question until you've have indicate that you have) but it seems that you haven't.

Comment: I'm familiar with that. I gave a two-line answer that is actually correct. I also gave more detail, to help someone who might want more detail. Nothing against that in the guidelines. You are cherry picking. I am going based on lines like "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better" that are also in the guidelines. I attempt to give fuller explanations of things. Focusing on character number seems stylistic pedantry, not substance. Indeed, there is a character limit, right, that embodies the strict limits? I'm not even halfway there in my answer. So there's that.

Comment: @neuronet Length is not stylistic.  The formatting of the text is something that's stylistic.  The scope of the content covered is in no way stylistic, it's substance.  You're trying to write a book, when the help center specifically said that you shouldn't be writing a book for an answer.  If you want to write books for answers that's fine, SO just isn't the place to do it.  There are lots of other places where it is fine.

Comment: focusing on length is not focusing on content. You have said nothing about the content, and are repeating yourself now, haven't really addressed my previous claim. I gave the tl;dr for people who want that, and a longer version for those who want more explanation. This is accepted practice, and you have given zero substantive critique of the substance of my answer, other than repeating what you think about long answers.

Comment: @neuronet The scope of the post is an aspect of the content of the post.  Or are you saying that two posts discussing the same topic, but with radically different scopes, have exactly the same content?  The scope of a post is highly relevant; discussing the technical accuracy of the statements is not the only possible criticism that can be made of a post.

Comment: @neuronet If the short answer is sufficient, then the rest of the post is just noise, and the post would be better off without it (or with it dramatically reduced).  If it's not, then the scope of the problem is too large.

Comment: obviously there are different levels of detail you can answer a question, and the longer one isn't necessarily noise. A good explanation is not noise. Again you are giving a priori generalities without anything specific at this point. Maybe point out the noise in my answer.

Comment: "If the short answer is sufficient, then the rest of the post is just noise." That's a tautology. I totally agree with [neuronet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1886357/neuronet), sometimes details are needed. For example if you think the person you are answering to is a beginner, then you can't just gave them a very evasive answer. And I think most questions are asked by beginners. An alternative is to use external references as much as possible, but this comes with a big drawback as external references are not guaranteed to stay forever.

Comment: @cglacet If you feel that that much information is all necessary than, as the answer states, *the question is too broad*.  If the question demonstrates such a significant lack of understanding of basic concepts that the answer needs to spend considerable time explaining related concepts for the answer to be understood *it is too broad of a question*.

Comment: Your logic doesn't seems right to me. A very short and precise question may need a long/broad/detailed/reasoned answer. For example this question: [_how to execute two “aggregate” functions (like sum) concurrently, feeding them from the same iterator_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50039223/1720199)  has a very long answer: [comparing different solutions' performances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51569789/1720199).  I wouldn't call that noise, I personally think it's a very good answer, it has everything you need to understand your options. An answer is sometime long because the problem is hard.

Comment: @cglacet I'm not an expert in the field but it sure looks like there's *lots* of information there that isn't needed, and it *greatly* reduces the quality of the post.  Including multiple wildly different solutions, instead of simply including the one bests suited to the situation, means that readers are forced to spend considerable time reading through information about solutions that aren't useful for them, just to find the one that they should use, or worse still, not selecting the proper solution for the situation at all, because such a solution was inappropriately included.

Comment: "Including  multiple wildly different solutions, instead of simply including the one bests suited to the situation" I agree that these two makes sense but achieve very different goals, I personally prefer the first. I think that's the fundamental reason why we disagree.

Comment: @cglacet Well it means fewer readers are going to get the correct solution to the problem, and many of the readers are going to end up being *actively harmed* by the solution and end up using a solution *inappropriate* to the situation at hand, as a result of the answer.  And the only benefit you've provided is that "it's longer", as if that's somehow intrinsically a good thing.

Comment: I never said "longer is better", I just said "longer doesn't mean bad". The benefit is, as I said, "it has everything you need to understand your options", that doesn't even evoke the size of the answer. It just happen to be long, but that's a consequence of being clear and reasoned. "fewer readers are going to get the correct solution to the problem",  you use "correct solution" as if it was something universal and absolute, but in many cases there is no such thing as "a correct solution".

Comment: For example if you have multi-variable algorithms, you'll have [multi-variable complexities](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Big_O_notation#/Multiple_variables) and therefore it may happen that existing algorithms can't even compare.

Comment: @cglacet Either one of the solutions is better than the others, in which case, people are using an inferior solution if they pick incorrectly, or there *is* on better solution, they're all equally good, and it's a waste of their time to look at any more than one solution.  Either way, it's not helpful to have so many different solutions to the problem.  It actively detracts from the quality of the answer, and makes it less helpful to readers.  The *best case*, is that it's just wasting a bunch of their time reading information that's not helpful to them.

Comment: I don't understand how you can consider valid information "not helpful" as the goal is to learn things.

Comment: @cglacet The goal is to solve the problem asked about.  Not to learn anything, even if it's not useful to solving the actual problem being asked about.  Posting an answer to that question explaining how to sort a list isn't helpful, regardless of how correct the information is because *it doesn't help you solve the problem at hand*.  The idea of the site is to have questions and answers to those questions, not questions and random information that may or may not actually be relevant, so long as it's factually correct.

Comment: If you just want to learn things in general, rather than solve specific problems, then SO's model isn't well suited to the situation.  If you just want to post random information for people to learn something arbitrary then write a tutorial, a blog, make a youtube video, etc.  SO's model is specific answers to specific questions.

Comment: Ok, it look like we can't talk, you keep extrapolating what I say, I never said "off topic information". We are talking about levels of details on a given subject, you say that details is noise, I just say that details are sometimes necessary to fully understand an answer. If the goal is just to "solve problems", then how do you explain questions like "how does X work under the hood?". There is no problem to solve, the problem has already been solved by someone else. That's just a question written to better understand something (and don't tell me the question is too broad, I never said that).

Comment: @cglacet A question like, "how does X work" is almost certainly going to be too broad, unless X is something *very* simple to which explaining how it works can be done succinctly.  It's also a fairly poor question because, as you have said, there isn't a problem to solve.  That makes it a poor question for this platform.  And you *have* indicated the information is off topic, because in response to me explaining why it's off offtopic your only response was to say, "but it's correct".  If it's actually a part of answering the question *explain why*, other than just that you like it.

Comment: I don't see any reason why a question should have a problem to solve. Concerning the off topic, you should just read back, we were talking about solutions that can't be compared, that's nothing off-topic at all, unless you also qualify complexity analysis as noise. Anyway, I'm bored arguing on details, when the existence of long questions by itself validates this feature request.

Comment: @cglacet The whole premise of the site is to provide answers to specific programming problems.  Not just to post anything without bound.  If you have a question in which you can't determine what the correct answer is then *that is not an acceptable question*, because it can't be answered as it.  It needs to have sufficient information added that an actual verifiable correct answer can be provided.

Comment: It is pretty clear in retrospect that generalities about length of posts are not helpful. It depends on the topic.  There are great, long, didactic posts. Eg Aaron Hall's python posts.  They belong here just as much as more terse posts.  Answer quality isn't decided by individual know-it-alls, and their arbitrary pronouncements about word counts, but by users and their votes.  That's Stack Overflow.

Comment: @neuronet So long posts are allowed just because you say so, but the fact that the site has created a Too Broad reason and specifically stated that post are expected to be reasonably scoped in their questions, and created both rules and technical changes in the site to enforce this, is just irrelevant?  Long form content can certainly be useful, it's just not what this site is designed to create.  Books, blogs, tutorials, classes, and other forms of content designed to provide lots of information on a broad topic can certainly be useful, but this site isn't designed to support it.

Comment: Reasonably scoped questions can have answers with high word counts. Just look at the data.

Comment: @neuronet If the answer requires a large amount of content then *by definition* the question wasn't narrow in scope.  The scope of the question is *by definition*, how much content is required for it to be answered.

Comment: @Servy "The scope of the question is by definition, how much content is required for it to be answered". This is where we disagree. You have been shown plenty of counterexamples. Have a good one.

Comment: @neuronet What do you think the scope of a question is, if not how much content is required to answer it?  That you've posted a few off topic broad questions doesn't mean that the scope of a question isn't based on how much content is needed to answer it.